# Do all Dask Workers need to be the same operating system?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I set up a cluster that appears to connect correctly to the scheduler (3 Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and 3 Windows 10 machines, scheduler is on one of the Win 10 machines).  I am getting a timeout error on code that I have successful run before when all of the OSs were Win 10.

Here is the error in all its glory:

```
tornado.application - ERROR - Multiple exceptions in yield list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\core.py", line 186, in connect
    quiet_exceptions=EnvironmentError)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
tornado.util.TimeoutError: Timeout

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 883, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 634, in send_recv_from_rpc
    comm = yield self.pool.connect(self.addr)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\core.py", line 745, in connect
    connection_args=self.connection_args)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\core.py", line 195, in connect
    _raise(error)
  File "C:\Apps\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\distributed\comm\core.py", line 178, in _raise
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://138.55.36.169:43033' after 10 s: connect() didn't finish in time
```

So this error repeats 3 times, with each ip being one of my linux machines.  This leads me to believe that maybe I can't have multiple operating systems in a dask cluster but I have not been able to find anything in documentation that says as such.  Am i doing something wrong or did I just miss this somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workers all need to be able to serialize and deserialize functions effectively.  So if the functions and data that you are using can be serialized on one OS and deserialized on the other and still execute then things should be fine.

In principle, this is true.  Python functions should work anywhere.  In practice though this may break if, for example, you have libraries present on one machine but not on another then there would be an issue.

The error that you present could be for a number of reasons, including different Python versions or network issues.

I recommend calling the following to check that versions of relevant libraries are the same across your Dask workers and client.

```
client.get_versions(check=True)
```

Comment: Thanks MRocklin!  In my case i had a version of a dependency called cloudpickle that was different between the linux and windows machines.  I installed anaconda at the same time on these machines and incorrectly assumed all of the included packages were the same version.  Any handy dask related function that can compare all packages between workers and scheduler?